# how to install asp.net 4.5 in visual studio 2012

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

i am using visual studio 2012. i want to develop asp .net application.I am getting this error when i go into File->new-> Web Site

"The web developer tool option must be installed prior to opening or creating web project. You can install this option by repairing your Microsoft Visual Studio installation and ensuring that 'Web Developer tools' is checked in the list of optional component"

how i am use asp.net. plz give me solution.
thanks in advance

Comment: You need to get the Visual Studio 2012 installer for whatever edition you have, and run the installer again and check "Web Developer Tools". Usually this is checked by default. The error message *is* the solution.

Comment: where i can find web developer tool

Comment: Wherever you got your Visual Studio installer in the first place.

Comment: @bheeshamkumarsharma Which version of VS are you using?  Express? Premium? Ultimate?

Comment: @bheeshamkumarsharma If it's Express, is it Express for Desktop, Express for Web, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two scenarios here for Visual Studio products:

**Express versions**

If you are using an Express version of VS, you need to install the VS Express for Web.  Each Express SKU is tailored to a specific type of development.

**Pro/Premium/Ultimate versions**

For these versions, you probably need to change the set of installed features:

1. Go to Add/Remove Programs (via Control Panel, or appwiz.cpl)
2. Find Visual Studio 2012 and right-click.  There will only be one option, "Change"
3. That will bring up a wizard with the features available for VS.  Make sure Web Development Tools is selected.
4. Install the new features.